# Javascript parseInt always returns NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone tell me why my `parseInt` function always retuns `NaN` in the Firebug console despite the string value always returns a number?

This is my debug script:

```
console.log($(this).val()+" - "+typeof($(this).val())+" - "+parseInt($(this).val));
```

Which yields:

```
1 - string - NaN
2 - string - NaN
5 - string - NaN
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
parseInt($(this).val())
```

Missing `()`'s

Comment: Crucially, without the `()`, you're passing a function to `parseInt`, not the *results* of the function.

Comment: Sorry for that fatal error and thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

You´re missing an ending "()". Try:

```
parseInt($(this).val())
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using val instead of val() on your parseInt